# Json code retrieved with AJAX is unparsable

Tags: php, json, jquery

I'm a beginner.

I write simple json jquery php code to help understand the idea of json, but its not work, please help me.(I didnt write $_Post, submit, click function etc.. because its not working with, soo I cut the code to find the problem)

The user enters view.html and should get an alert box with value Bob - the problem is the user doesn't get the alert box.

**view.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" 
        src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $.ajax({
          url: 'controller.php',
          type: 'post',
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function (data) {
              alert(data["userdata"]["first"]);
          }
      });
  });​
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

**controller.php:**

```
<?php
  $arr=array();
  $arr['userdata']['first']='Dan';
  echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

Thanks for help

Comment: I don't see any errors in the code. Try debugging using Chrome WebDeveloper->Resources (or Firebug->Net) and see if you get the proper content of controller.php. Does it return status 200?

Comment: I get: 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the correct JSON header to your PHP file.

```
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

Answer (score 2):

You will to check your apache's mod_security settings. This could be causing your  503 Service Temporarily Unavailable

Answer (score 0):

Thank to Jan I find the problem: my local zend server not worked (because i didnt define password for zend community server) when i fix it its starts working

Comment: Perhaps you could add a bit more detail, e.g. what the problem was/how it was fixed--in case someone else getting 503 errors during their AJAX requests stumbles on this page.